# jquery div element hover changes txt element in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-hover, webflow

The website I'm building using webflow is my first delve into jquery (or j anything).  I'm not a dev in any language but typically can get things to work with enough research.... not this time  :)

My team collection page has a button made from a div ('.DivTeamBtn') with text ('.TxtTeamBtn')

When the button is clicked the team members description changes between 2 div blocks:

```
('.Div Flex Center.TeamFun') when display: none - on ('.DivTeamBtn')hover ('.TxtTeamBtn).text(hSudo)

('.Div Flex Center.TeamActual') when display: none - on ('.DivTeamBtn')hover ('.TxtTeamBtn).text(hFact)
```

What I am trying to accomplish is: mouse hover ('.DivTeamBtn') changes ('.TxtTeamBtn') text based on which div block display property is 'none'.

For now I'm just trying to get on hover to work via jquery.  This is what I have... and nothing is working (that I can see).

[Webflow read only link](https://preview.webflow.com/preview/agave-it-services?utm_medium=preview_link&utm_source=designer&utm_content=agave-it-services&preview=d292fbe6dd0897496cd4792c4ff74e4b&pageId=5eb5f3d9580ee3e81a2302ee&itemId=5eb5f3d9580ee30bed230441&mode=preview) This is on the teams collection page

```
    <script>
Webflow.push(function() {

  // Hover text change
$( function() {
var nh = 'Click Me!';
var hSudo = 'For sudo facts';
var hFact = 'For facts';
$('.DivTeamBtn').hover(function(){
    $('.TxtTeamBtn').text(hfun);
}, function() {
    $('.TxtTeamBtn').text(nh);
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hey Matthew, some tip: You have better chances for help if you provide a runnable snippet with all the html, js and css needed. Then we can use it for playing around and checking our solutions. (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: Not sure quite how to do that Paul... however I have found a way around writing custom code to accomplish what I'm trying to do.
Since the button is present for each div I just added to button inside of each div which aloud me to have a specific hover action on 2 buttons....  Instead of one button where I would programmatically decide which text to show on hover.